# Merging 1000s of files into one sorted file with memory constraints - heap vs bucket sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, heapsort, bucket-sort, external-sorting

The numbers are unique within each file and across all files. Here is one popular approach (external sorting) to merge n files into one sorted file when our compute machine cannot store all the data:

- Sort each smaller file
- Read first elements from each file
- Create a heap
- while heap is not empty:

  - write min element to final file
  - insert next element from the smaller file (whose element was written to the main file in step above) into the heap

While I do understand how this algorithm helps in memory usage - there's a lot of I/O overhead involved.

Another possible approach uses bucket sort - specially if numbers are uniformly distributed:

- Create n buckets - (max_num-min_number)/number_of_elements_in_1_bucket
- For each smaller file:

  - read file
  - create a batch update dictionary {bucket_number:[list of elements]}
  - Append data from above dictionary to respective bucket files
  - The dictionary space is limited so only 100 elements at a time can be processed for each smaller file. So above 2 steps are repeated until we have exhausted the current file elements
- For each bucket file created

  - sort data in each bucket
- append all files together into a single sorted file

Now, I believe the latter approach can be slightly faster or at least equivalent in terms of time complexity, but uses more storage space for temp files. Are these 2 approaches comparable in **time complexity** or 1st one is always better even after multiple I/O calls? Am I missing some time-consuming step in the 2nd approach that makes it less optimum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that it is the other way around.  If numbers have a predictable distribution in a predictable range, bucket sort is faster.  (In the limit `O(n)` vs `O(n log(n))` for comparison based sorts.) Better yet, buckets can be sorted independently from each other.  Which makes them perfect for a distributed sort.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @btilly. I was having a debate with someone who seemed to think otherwise.